# Metabase is not showing synonyms

Tags: ssms, metabase

I want to define the relationship between a table I am joining, and the table I am joining it too.
The table I am joining on is a synonym of another database's table. I am doing it this way because the other database is a data warehouse of some sort, while the database that its the synonym for is more detailed data that I can access with id's and such off of the synonym.

However, in metabase, the synonym just doesn't show up. I can query off of them but I cannot configure them in the admin menu.

I am current trying it like so:

```sql
FROM dwBdgtAdmnstrtn AS relation
LEFT JOIN rdLctn ON rdLctn.id = relation.lctn
LEFT JOIN crmRltnGrp ON crmRltnGrp.id = relation.rltnGrp
```

relation is the synonym I am joining on to, and location and relationgroup are the 2 tables I want to define relationship to the synonym with so that I can use linked filters.

The query is functioning correctly, but without a relationship closely defined the linked filters don't work.

Comment: sql-server is a different product from MySQL. Which are you actually using?

Comment: I've removed the conflicting wording/tags for now; you will need to [edit] the question  to (re)tag the (R)DBMS you are really using.

Comment: I am using SSMS, ive edited the stags to include ssms

Comment: Telling us you use SSMS is like telling us the car you drive is a Sony, because that's the name you see on the dashboard radio. Fine more most, but alarming from a mechanic.

Comment: Sorry. To be specific: Microsoft SQL server dev edition. 16.0.1000 rtm.